# model = hub.load(module_handle) is throwing error

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub

module_handle = "https://tfhub.dev/google/faster_rcnn/openimages_v4/inception_resnet_v2/1"
model = hub.load(module_handle)
```

Above code snippet is throwing error as follows in pycharm environment. Any idea why it is throwing error ?

OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: C:\Users\sethu\AppData\Local\Temp\tfhub_modules\6e850c920451d5243d1fb87a3242c087535b9183/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me so the URL looks good. Note that TF Hub [caches models locally](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/caching#:%7E:text=The%20tensorflow_hub%20library%20by%20default,have%20been%20downloaded%20from%20tfhub.&text=The%20download%20location%20defaults%20to,command%2Dline%20flag%20%2D%2Dtfhub_cache_dir%20.). Have you checked that this directory & file(s) exists?

```
C:\Users\sethu\AppData\Local\Temp\tfhub_modules\6e850c920451d5243d1fb87a3242c087535b9183/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb
```

Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63106499/2202359) try deleting the directory and running your code again.